# Initialization of a pointer to polymorphic object

Tags: pointers, fortran, polymorphism

Suppose I have a pointer to a polymorphic object:

```
TYPE, ABSTRACT:: ab
ENT TYPE

TYPE, EXTENDS(ab):: co
  INTEGER:: i
ENT TYPE

Class(ab), POINTER:: foo
```

How do I initialize the object pointed by `foo` to be a `co` object, in the executable part of the code? I am thinking of something like

```
foo => co(1)  ! WRONG
```

but this is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointers can only be initialized with a target with the `save` attribute or with `null()`. If you mean the initialization during compilation in the declaration part.

In the executable part of code you can certainly make the pointer to point to an object. But you need an actual object with the `target` attribute or you need to make an anonymous target using the `allocate()` statement.

`co(1)` is an expression or a value result of an expression. You cannot point to it, it does not have the pointer attribute. You could allocate an anonymous target with this value

```
allocate(foo, source=co(1))
```

Consider using `allocatable` instead of a `pointer`, they should be strongly preferred. If you could use allocatable, it is as simple as

```
foo = co(1)
```

thanks to the automatic (re)allocation in the assignment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I meant initialization in the executable part; I have edited the question to clarify that. What you suggest, that is, using `ALLOCATABLE`, is actually what I am doing now. However, my problem is that I actually have multiple such allocatables which such be grouped somehow in the code, and may be of different dynamic type. My current solution is to have a wrapper type for a single `CLASS(ab)` allocatable, and then an array of wrapper types. The problem with this is that the wrapper type feels redundant to me, and makes the code less clean, doubling the amount of `%`.

Comment: IanH, thanks. @Frank, in that case the `allocate()` should do it for you if you need pointers.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, but I have just learned that I cannot have an array of pointers in Fortran (right?), so it seems like I cannot get rid of the wrapper type...

Comment: Right, no arrays of pointers in Fortran.